# rdlc Report print when width is more than height automatic landscape mode

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reportviewer, rdlc

When i'm printing it automatically coming as landscape mode i'm using i'm tried many things but no use can any one tell me a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Your RDLC will have page Height and Width properties.  If you want portrait mode, you'll need to make sure these properties are set to 8.5" x 11".

Comment: My page size is 8"width and 5.45" height. i have set this size for pre printed paper

Comment: I also encounter this problem width 8 and height 5.5 automatic landscape

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust page properties by right clicking report and select page setting then select potrait or just checks tools for more option i have use RDLC reports since long ago thats why not sure where is the option but pretty sure about page setting. May this helps you solve your problem.

Go to report menu there you will find page settings

Comment: its in portrait but its automatically going to landscape.when i'm set the height greater than width its printing portrait,but my page size is  8"width and 5.45" height for pre printed paper

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem once.  What I did was place the same width and height in rdlc.

This way, the system assumes that it can be portrait, but the information you want to print must be placed at the bottom of the report.

good luck.